# std::vector hex values

Tags: c++, hex

How do you initialize an `std::vector` with hex values? The follow throws an error:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vect ("oc","d4","30");
```

---

If I have a string value that containes a base64 code like: "DNQwSinfOUSSWd+U04r23A==" ....how can I put it in a std::vectorv?

std::string = "DNQwSinfOUSSWd+U04r23A==";

I first want to decode it to hexa values. After that to put it in a vector. Can someone please tell me how to decode the string value that contains base64 encoder into a hexa?

Comment: I'm working on C++ - IN linux

Comment: "oc" sure is a funny hex value.

Comment: You **need** to get some concepts straight before moving on. "oc", "d4", "30" are not hex values, they are zero terminated strings. You need some data conversion there - and when this is done, you can go work with vectors ;)

Comment: @marcog: You added the template parameter list in a quiet edit. I'd only change formatting and typos in someone else's question; if the code is wrong for other reasons than given in the question, then this should be pointed out in an answer so that the OP can see it and learn from it.

Comment: @Tomalak No they were just hidden by formatting issues (`<unsigned char>` being interpreted as an html tag). See [the original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/80dffeea-5b92-4ca7-8bef-17201bc95485/view-source).

Comment: @marcog: Ah, apologies! Seems like a nice little SO bug?

Comment: @Tomalak It's quite a frequent problem. Sometimes a whole block of code is interpreted as HTML and becomes invisible until formatted correctly. :(

Comment: @marcog: I'm astounded! The software is, generally, brilliant.

Comment: @Tomalak: not a bug. Stack Overflow allows HTML input (but sanitizes it). If you don’t want your code interpreted as HTML, mark it as code. It’s not a bug, it’s (really) a feature.

Comment: @Konrad, @Tomalak: although I wonder why it allows HTML input at all. It seems that its only purpose is to allow newcomers to do some pseudo code-formatting which (as shown here) doesn't really work.

Comment: @jalf. Very true. Although I use HTML for footnotes (`<sup>`) and to indicate obsolete text (`<del>`). But I agree that allowing HTML is a pathetic display of Markdown’s abilities.

Answer (score 15):

(You forgot to give your `std::vector` an element type. I'll assume `unsigned char`.)

In C++0x you will be able to write:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v{ 0x0C, 0xD4, 0x30 };
```

In C++03 you have to write:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(0x0C);
v.push_back(0xD4);
v.push_back(0x30);
```

Or, if you don't mind using up the space:

```
unsigned char values[] = { 0x0C, 0xD4, 0x30 };
std::vector<unsigned char> v(values, values+3);
```

You could also look at [boost.assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Comment: `unsigned char` would be more appropriate than `char` here.

Comment: @ypnos: I don't mind the type edit, but you removed one of my sentences. I wanted the OP to be very clear that he did not include a template parameter list, where one is required. Please do not change my words.

Comment: @ypnos: Turns out the OP had included it, but a SO HTML issue had mangled it. Apologies. (Would still prefer my words not being altered, though!)

Comment: Thx a lot. The second example, the one with C++03 works perfectly. I do have one more question. If I have a string value that containes a base64 code like: "DNQwSinfOUSSWd+U04r23A==" ....how can I put it in a std::vector<char>v?

Comment: `std::string base64 = "DNQwSinfOUSSWd+U04r23A=="; std::vector<char> v(base64.begin(), base64.end());`

Comment: @eliza: Forgot to highlight your name. See comment above for response.